# What is this strange animation of a pulsar likely trying to illustrate? One beam is normal, the opposite gets wrapped like coiled rope?

Tags: neutron-star

The November 2020 Sixty Symbols video *How Smooth is a Neutron Star?* (linked below) describes negative LIGO results looking for weak but very periodic signals from rotating neutron stars that might radiate gravitational waves due to higher order mass moments.

It shows a lot of animations of neutron stars and pulsars, and some of them feel a bit off to me, often it looks like the beam axis doesn't define a pair of cones as it rotates, as if someone was moving it around by hand instead of using a proper trajectory.

But this image below really confuses me! It shows two "beams" emitted from the poles of a sphere that is presumably a neutron star. One shoots almost straight up, the other extends down but it then coils itself on to a fixed circular loop, like coiled rope.

**Question**: What is this strange animation of a pulsar likely trying to illustrate? One beam is normal, the opposite gets wrapped like coiled rope?

[image: screenshot from the Sixty Symbols video "How Smooth is a Neutron Star"?]

Comment: I’m not sure if this is true, but I’m guessing a very similar shape would be seen just above where the camera cuts off; I think it’s just showing how the outflow of photons/ particles makes that shape as it propagates in space after moving how it is? Just a guess

Answer (score 3):

As already pointed out by [Justin T](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/49066/what-is-this-strange-animation-of-a-pulsar-likely-trying-to-illustrate-one-beam/49068#comment107846_49066)'s comment, this is just a symmetrical emission profile seen from the top.
This is the full animation, which shows the pattern from various angles and should makes this more clear:

[image]

Comment: Okay I'm slowly getting it, thanks! I think part of the problem is that the "camera" or viewing position used to generate the animation is at a finite distance, and my brain always defaults to [orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection) in which case the behavior would be symmetric and conical. The reason it looks like a circle is that the viewer is sitting *near* the apex of the outgoing cone of "blue fuzzy photon spray" (i.e. [perspective projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_(graphical)))